# Javascript: setTimeout() not working

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I can't seem to get the setTimeOut() function working. Below is the javascript that I have been working on:

```
    function hideImage()
    {
        document.getElementById('loadingimg').style.visibility='hidden';        
    }
    function showImage()
    {
        document.getElementById('loadingimg').style.visibility='visible';
        setTimeOut(hideImage, 3000);
    }
```

Whenever I call the function showImage(), the gif image is displayed in the page. However, the image does not hide after 3 seconds, even though I called the setTimeOut() method.

Comment: setTimeout() not setTimeOut()

Comment: `setTimeOut -> setTimeout` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: pro tip : use `window.setTimeout(func,delay)`

Comment: thanks guys, I appreciate the prompt response. I realized I was being careless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yani and others are right. Its case sensitivity error. Just FYI, here is my piece of working code for you:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="Init()">
<img id="loadingimg" height="24" width="24" src="ball.gif">
<script type="text/javascript">

function hideImage()
    {
        document.getElementById('loadingimg').style.visibility='hidden';        
        //document.getElementById('loadingimg').style.display = "none";
    }
    function showImage()
    {
        document.getElementById('loadingimg').style.visibility='visible';
        setTimeout(hideImage, 3000);
    }
function Init()
{
    showImage();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>


Regards,
dennis
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `setTimeOut` to `setTimeout`. It's case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Case mistake.

Try `setTimeout` rather than `setTimeOut`.